# PHP: Почему в телеграм бот публикует текст со сломанной кодировкой?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Сделал telegram-бот с вебхуком. Если пользователь выбирает в боте определенную команду, то размещенный на сервере скрипт, с которым связан вебхук должен ответить в чат текстовым сообщением на кириллице..

Увы, получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скрипт файла, на который прокидывается вебхук такой:

$textMessage = "Вы помните знаменитое стихотворение Бориса Пастернака Во всем мне хочется дойти... Введите первую строчку стихотворения, а ПопугайПастернака подскажет вам следуюдующу. Сможете дойти вместе с ботом до конца стихотворения?";

```
$textMessage = urlencode($textMessage);
$urlQuery = "https://api.telegram.org/bot". $token ."/sendMessage?chat_id=". $chat_id ."&text=" . urlencode($textMessage);
$result = file_get_contents($urlQuery);
```

Интересно, что какое-либо сообщение пишется только если дважды сделать urlencode() с $textMessage, в противном случае bad request отдает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

определил кодировку $textMessage в файле, реагирующем на хук, там она UTF-8. Специалисты, не подскажете, что можно предпринять?

Comment: ты же сам пишешь `urlencode`........

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если убрать один или все urlencode, то вообще не отправиться в телегу с сервера. ьудет ошибка bad request 400

Comment: а если банально хардкорно написать `"......."&text=Проверка текста"`  то что будет?

Comment: отправьте вы post запросом добро это

Comment: @teran через `file_get_contents` тоже вполне норм.

Comment: @Valentin  Попробуй так `$params = [
 'text' => 'Моё сообщение',
 'chat_id' => 555,
 'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
];
$botId = 111;

$requestString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$botId}/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($params);

file_get_contents($requestString);`

Comment: или сделай ОДИН РАЗ urlencode.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский попробовал  так: $urlQuery = "https://api.telegram.org/bot". $token ."/sendMessage?chat_id=". $chat_id ."&text=Проверка текста"; то отдает 400 Warning: : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /var/www/u0189754/data/www/englishforcing.ru/tgBot/index.php on line 21

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если одну оставить urlencode, то такая ошибка: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org//sendMessage?chat_id=&text=%C2%FB+%EF%EE%EC%ED%EE5%F2+%E2%E0%EC+%F1%EB%E5%E4%F3%FE%E4%F3%FE%F9%F3.+%D1%EC%EE%E6%E5%F2%E5+%E4%EE%E9%F2%E8+%E2%EC%E5%F1%F2%E5+%F1+%E1%EE%F2%EE%EC+%E4%EE+%EA%EE%ED%F6%E0+%F1%F2%E8%F5%EE%F2%E2%EE%F0%E5%ED%E8%FF%3F): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /var/www/u0189754/data/www/englishforcing.ru/tgBot/index.php on line 21

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тоже не отправляет так пишет (начальную чать url опустил): sendMessage?text=%CC%EE%B8+%F1%EE%EE%E1%F9%E5%ED%E8%E5&chat_id=-947172522&parse_mode=HTML): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /var/www/u0189754/data/www/englishforcing.ru/tgBot/index.php on line 24

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если курлом и пост запросом пытаешься отправить, то вот что выдает: stdClass Object ( [ok] => [error_code] => 400 [description] => Bad Request: message text is empty )

Comment: *"определил кодировку $textMessage в файле, реагирующем на хук, там она UTF-8."* --- попробуй не просто utf , но UTF-8 без BOM.  Чтобы это сделать, можно открыть *Nodepad++* и в меню выбрать encoding -> encode in UTF-8 without BOM. Только желательно всё скопировать в буфер. а то может в коде что-то в крякозябры перевестись

Comment: @АлексейШиманский самое интересное, из WSL в тот же бот кириллический шрифт отправляю, нормально публикуется.... А тут скрипт на сервере выкладываю, чтоб постоянно на хуки отвечал и перестает работать..

Comment: Возможно когда копируешь на сервер (например через filezilla), то происходит автоматическая конвертация каких-нибудь русских символов в коде. Поэтому надо на серваке посмотреть этот код, может он там корявый лежит. Поэтому например туда напрямую код из буфера обмена вставить и сохранить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если английскими буквами текст пишу, то все отправляется благополучно в бот

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не, в этом плане все норм должно быть.... я его сам редактирую прямо на сервере... он неповрежден

Comment: ну отправлять правильно будет либо с одним urldencode либо так, как я показал с http_build_query, чтобы проблем с русским не было... с кодировкой сказал... пока больше не знаю что ещё может быть))  разве что где-то либо в коде, либо в хуке либо в настройках бота прописано "вырезать русские символы" перед отправкой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский заработало, Алексей, спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

После энного количества мучений, вот так заработало:

```
$pl = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", "Заработаю я когда-то или нет");
//$pl = urlencode($pl);
$data = ["text" => $pl];
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        $curlErr = curl_error($ch);
        print_r($result);
```

url кодирование кириллицы не понадобилось, наверное, телега как-то это сама делает, ну и использовал пост, а не гет